# Gridview not rendered

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have bound gridview to Linq result and set AutoGenerateColumns to true and Enabled Viewstate for the grid view and Still not rendered at all ,Html in browser shows empty

```
   <div></div>
```

What is weird is that in ASP.NET development server in file system it is VISIBLE with no problem but When I hosted it in Internet it is not !!

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <Triggers>
         <asp:asyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1"  EventName="Click" />

 </Triggers>

<ContentTemplate >
   <asp:GridView dir="rtl" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
     AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4"  AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
     ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Vertical"  ViewStateMode="Enabled"
     Width="917px" style=" padding-bottom:20px;" EnableViewState="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
        HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>

  <br />
  <br />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

By the way I tried also to remove the Ajax control but It did not solve the problem

The Linq code is pretty complicated but I can Show you this

```
     tmp = (From p In results Where p.ShowProduct
            Select New With {.المادة = p.ProductName,
                                     .السعر = If(p.Setting.ShowPrices, If(p.ShowPrice, (p.SellPrice * p.Setting.ConversionToDollar).ToString, " - "), " - "),
                                        .الكمية = If(p.Setting.ShowCounts, If(p.ShowCount, CSng(p.Count) & " " & p.Unit, " - "), " - "),
                                        .الصنف = p.Category,
                                        .الوصف = p.Description,
                                        .المنشأ = p.Manufacturer,
                                        .المحل = If(p.Setting.ShowAddress,
                                                    If(p.Setting.ShowMobile,
                                                       p.Setting.NameOfShop & "/" & p.Setting.ShopAddress & "/" & p.Setting.Mobile,
                                                       p.Setting.NameOfShop & "/" & p.Setting.ShopAddress & "/ -"),
                                                   If(p.Setting.ShowMobile,
                                                      p.Setting.NameOfShop & "/ - /" & p.Setting.Mobile,
                                                  p.Setting.NameOfShop & "/ - / - ")),
                                     .التاريخ = p.LastUpdate}).ToList.OrderByDescending(Function(n) n.GetType().GetProperty(GridViewSortExpression).GetValue(n, Nothing)).ToList


    End If

    ResultCount = results.Count
    GridView1.DataSource = tmp
    ' GridView1.ViewStateMode = UI.ViewStateMode.Enabled
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

I also tried to put this line of code

```
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
```

Please help me

Comment: Is the linq query returning results in the live env?

Comment: Yes ,You can see the variable ResultCount ,it returns actual rows count as expected but the gridview is absent **only online (Internet)** !!!

Comment: Results is the collection that you're querying from, of course its gonna have a count. In the live environment, does the variable tmp  have any data in it after the linq query is executed?

Comment: Yes the tmp variable is not nothing,and actually I tried also putting the results as a datasource and nothing happended,I noticed one thing when I remove gridview1.databind the gridview disappear from development env also,So I was thinking If the data in live env is lost somehow and the gridview is always empty and it's columns are not rendered because they r auto generated ? any Idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is no errors in my code but the reason for Gridview not being rendered is that it is the datasource is empty because Although the query (Results) is not nothing the second query (tmp) is actually empty because of the condition (Where p.ShowProduct) which I thought it is True And after checking the Db I found that All values in this field are Null .

Thank you

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I have a completely dynamic gridview which was not getting rendered when it was empty. I had ShowHeaderWhenEmpty set to true and it still only gave me '<div></div>', but setting a datasource to a new List<string>() worked perfectly to force it to render.